# SocketException (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, winsock

I have a simple program on my test machine that try to connect to a server address and it will fail with an exception.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                const string ipaddr = "172.217.5.10";
                using (Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
                {
                    sock.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ipaddr), 80);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output of this simple program is:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 172.217.5.10:80
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,  SocketAddress socketAddress)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
>          at HttpClientTests.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:.test-projects\Test\Program.cs:line 16

The browsers on my system work perfectly fine and I don't know what is wrong that I get the error.
I also tested the exact same functionality with native(C++) code and it will fail in VisualStudio but run from command line.
The Code that compiled on my system, works perfectly fine on other systems in my domain.
I'm using Windows 10 and VS2015.2.

I also tested my program with Wireshark and I see my SYN, the server's SYN ACK and then RST from my side.

Can anyone help me to find the cause of this error please?

Comment: Do you have outgoing Firewall rules that could cause that?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer no I have no outgoing firewall and I am also able to use my browsers perfectly normal

Comment: @BigBoss Was there any resolution to your issue? I get a similar result when invoking `OAuth GetRequestToken` (DevDefined.OAuth)

Comment: @rahul source of my problem was my anti virus(kaspersky), after I removed my anti virus every thing worked just fine

Comment: @bigboss thanks, my issue was indeed related to kaspersky

Comment: @BigBoss any solution found for this problem?